# Is there any component of opinion based in Indra's question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, down-votes

I recently posted a [question and its answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43683/is-there-any-modern-interpretation-for-indra-curse-to-women-and-other-entities).

Question received 3 down-votes and answer received 2 down-votes and 2 close votes.

In the body of the question, I clearly asked that

> *Are there any modern **scriptural interpretations** for this story*

I am not asking for individual opinions, I am asking for possible scriptural interpretations only.

Since I heard in a video of my own language of a well-reputed preacher about this interpretation, I researched myself and posted the question and answer.

I know that there are some users who down-vote may not agree with the interpretation, but no comments has been received so far regarding the down-votes or close votes together question or answer.

So, I want to discuss about the merits or downsides of the question and answer, if any.

Comment: Even if question is not opinion based I have seen people closing it as such many a times in the past and I guess it happens even now .. So bottom line is we can not expect all people to think and act in the correct possible manner. Problem arises when majority can't take the right decision otherwise it's ok :D

Comment: It is unfortunate but some users here are exceptionally heavy close-voter and down-voter. One Swamiji for example. He thinks every other question does not belong to Hinduism... His definition of Hinduism is exceptionally narrow. Hinduism on the other hand teaches us to be broadminded.